# idp_cert_or_fingerprint_not_found_and_required attempting to validate authnrequest

Tags: saml, onelogin

I am attempting to use https://www.samltool.com/validate_authn_req.php to validate a saml request. I have fed it the samlrequest, the signature, relaystate, base64 encoded token signing cert from SP and sigalg. Yet it complains of idp_cert_or_fingerprint_not_found_and_required. I don't know why it needs the private key of the IDP given that the request has nothing encrypted within it.

I am hoping Onelogin folk like @smartin will see this and have a suggestion. Else, does anyone else have any tips on another way I can confirm if the signature received with a SAML authnrequest is valid?

Comment: Can you post your Authnrequest here?

Comment: Sorry I'd rather not as its from a production environment. I wrote a little tool based on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2008/06/25/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-signature-with-net-and-a-certificate-c/

Comment: Fwiw, I just tried using this same tool with an AuthN Request that I know to be valid, and I got the same error. I typically don't sign my AuthN Requests, but if you must, you should be able to verify them with a tool that understands XML digital signatures such as https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/xmldsig-verifier.html.

Comment: Fix coming soon as per https://mobile.twitter.com/LaCaraB/status/1003806421174145025?s=09